# What was the story about a man with an eye on his tongue/finger?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read a short story once (I don't know when) about wishes, or at least I think it was wishes, involving a man and a woman. The man ended up with an eye on his figure and tongue I think, or perhaps it was a small man in the persons mouth. At one point the eye-on-the-finger is used to see man in the mouth.

I'm sorry I have so little to go on, it was a long time ago that I read the story. I hope this enough to go on. It may have been a kid's story.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I should have known [TV Tropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EyesDoNotBelongThere) would have led me to the answer. It's called [*Tonsil Eye 'Tis*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirky_Tails#Tonsil_Eye_.27Tis):

> A boy who is obsessed with garden gnomes gets a gnome with a face in its mouth. After getting the face out of the gnome's mouth, the boy ends up getting the face in his own mouth, as well as an eye growing on his finger.